# MySQL numberplate relevence search performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, search, full-text-search

I am having a slight problem and would really appreciate the help please.

I have a MyISAM table containing 33,000,000 rows with the following data structure:

```
id -> Primary Key, Unsigned INT, Auto-Increment
characters -> Unique Indexed, varchar(15)
price -> decimal (10,2)
active -> tinyint(1)
```

I have written a script that takes a search value from the user and then creates the following query, based on the user typing in "Kevin":

```
SELECT characters, price 
FROM listings_dvla 
WHERE active=TRUE 
AND LOWER(REPLACE(characters, ' ', '')) REGEXP '^[a-z0-9]*[(k)]+[a-z0-9]?[(e)(3)]+[a-z0-9]?[(v)]+[a-z0-9]?[(i)(1)]+[a-z0-9]?[(n)(11)(1v)]+[a-z0-9]*' 
ORDER BY characters ASC 
LIMIT 0, 12
```

Just to explain, the regexp is just trying to match each letter in order, or a sequence of letters that mean the same in "number plate language" eg. N == 1V

Thing is, this query takes god damn ages! 20+ seconds. I have been reading around a fair amount and found out that having characters as the primary key was slower so I took that out and added an ID field. I have used EXPLAIN which shows the index's and they are NULL, I assume this is because REGEXP disables them (I read that somewhere too).

My question is, has anyone got any bright ideas to severely increase this queries performance? As I feel like I am unaware of something quite critical to get this to be faster.

I will change the table structure if need be so don't worry about giving me a rather extreme answer.

Thanks for reading this, would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is the timing any different if you remove the LOWER and REPLACE on the characters column ? Generally you want to avoid doing string operations on the columns in your where clause, as indexes are unlikely to be used. Also test with a straight `characters = 'kevin' , or something that matches exactly. You might be better off adjusting the user input in code, and rather run several queries instead of one query that does a regexp match and manipulates the column you search in.

Answer (score 0):

String queries are very slow in mysql. I'm not even sure whether any keys (except of `FULLTEXT` appliest to them).

You're using functions on where condition that means that **every records** has to be loaded, updated with replace and lower and than compared against regexp (mysql has no way of knowing in advance what the result will be).

Basically: with this kind of regexp you'll never have this query fast.

However you may add field such as `isWord TINYINT DEFAULT 0` (with index on it) and use query:

```sql
UPDATE listings_dvla SET isWord = 1 WHERE active=TRUE 
AND LOWER(REPLACE(characters, ' ', '')) REGEXP '^[a-z0-9]*[(k)]+[a-z0-9]?[(e)(3)]+[a-z0-9]?[(v)]+[a-z0-9]?[(i)(1)]+[a-z0-9]?[(n)(11)(1v)]+[a-z0-9]*'
```

And than select records by **indexed field* with: `SELECT ... WHERE ... AND isWord = 1`

Comment: The update query would need to be run first though, so that would take just as long as just searching for it normally? Or am I misunderstanding you here?

Comment: @KevinOrriss yes, first it would take 20+ seconds but I can't imagine it work faster

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you could "clean" the characters field so you don't have to convert it to lower and strip the spaces. This action almost certainly means you're missing the benefit of any indexing.

Secondly, the obvious alternative is to run the code which modifies "kevin" into its various numberplate forms on the client, and convert this into an "in" query:

```
select *
from listings_dvla 
where active = 1
and cleaned_characters in ('kev1n', 'kev1iv'.....)
```

If you also want to be able to search for words within the characters - i.e return A10 KEV for the parameter KEV, you can cheat a little by creating additional columns with the substrings.

table listings_dvla

```
ID    characters   cleaned_characters   characters_right7  characters_right6 characters_right5 characters_right4 characters_right3
1     A10 KEV       a10kev               10kev               0kev             kev     
2     KT 11 TCP     kt11tcp              t11tcp               11tcp           1tcp     tcp
```

Dirty, but by creating an index on all the columns, you should be able to get very quick queries. Insert/update would be slower, though...

Comment: Lets say I searched for "kev", your query would fail to find number plate "A10 KEV". Searching for an exact seems very fast, its only until I try to use LIKE or REGEXP does it slow down.

Comment: Ah, right - hadn't looked at the reg exp in enough detail to pick that up. LIKE and REGEXP will almost certainly not use the index; have modified the answer to show how to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

since you are not using the ID field in your where clause, mysql is not using your primary key. no surprises there.

I guess, what you need is a FULL TEXT index on your character column.